# OLE pdf control

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ole, visual-foxpro

I need a low level OLE control for reading, creating and modifying pdf files. I will use it with Visual FoxPro. By low level I mean that I won't need any extra software to install on the client machine.

Long story short, I need something like iText.

Preferably free or cheap.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuickPDF includes a pure Win32 DLL based version and is reasonably cheap at $249 with no runtime license fees. You would just need to copy the DLL in the same directory as your application.

[www.quickpdf.com](http://www.quickpdf.com)

Comment: Well thanks a lot! They actually have a free version with limited functionality, the one I need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean about "open"ing DLLs, however, VFP CAN make calls to DLLs via DECLARE statements to expose them... its done quite regularly with many Windows API calls.

However, you specific need of dealing with PDFs to modify poses another question... What is it you plan on trying to "modify"?

Comment: It was bad expression with opening dlls. By modify I meant, to open pdf file, print some strings on it and save it back or save to new file. I was successful with this, but I used dlls made in dot net and I would need dot net installed on client machine, so this is what I am trying to avoid. Thanks for your interest in my problem.